# How inflate a Linear layout with custom view by databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I just want to make a map with some **Vertical LinearLayout** that in each of that have a **Horizontal LinearLayout** and in each of this layout wanna inflate a view that is like below code :

each_cell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
    <variable name="live" type="Integer" />
    <variable name="i" type="Integer" />
    <variable name="j" type="Integer" />
</data>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/itemView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:setI="@{i}"
    app:setJ="@{j}"/>
```

each_row.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/row_instance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

that I will add this **Horizontal LL** view to my main **Vertical LL** and the map will created

and kotlin code :

```
            val cell = DataBindingUtil.inflate<EachCellBinding>(inflater , R.layout.each_cell , HorizontalLinearLayout.row_instance , true   )
```

but the error is :

```
Required DataBindingComponent is null in class EachCellBindingImpl. A BindingAdapter in com.example.gameoflife.SartFragment.StartFragment is not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods static.
```

Comment: Where you have declared binding adapter for methods app:setI and app:setJ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the error you have declared the binding adapter methods in `com.example.gameoflife.SartFragment.StartFragment`. Declaring it inside a class makes it non-static. But the binding adapter methods should be always static. So take the methods from inside the class and put it outside the class and it will become static and your error will be resolved.

Comment: tnx , i put it on the fragment class and yes when put it outside it my problem solved